# Run PSQL queries stored as strings in bash

Tags: bash, shell, psql, quotes

I'm trying to do a script that runs queries in PostgreSQL. I'm struggling with something that seems pretty simple (but does not work...).

- I have a set of queries stored as an array of strings, lets' say

```
query1="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='KeywordList';"
query2="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='AuthorList';"
queries=($query1 $query2)
```

- Then, I want to run this query in PSQL through a loop:

```
for query in "${queries[@]}" 
do
    psql $db_name -c "$query"
done
```

This gives me the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "COUNT"
LINE 1: COUNT(id)
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 1: FROM
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "nodes"
LINE 1: nodes
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: WHERE
        ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "label"
LINE 1: label='KeywordList';
```

- But this works when I give to PSQL the string itself: `psql $db_name -c "$query1"` (this returns me `10`).

I think that this is a quoting problem, or maybe Bash tries to understand what is in the string... I can not resolve this on my own after many tries with double, single and back quotes.

Help will be really appreciated, Nelly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is:

```
$ query1="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='KeywordList';"
$ query2="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='AuthorList';"
$ queries=($query1 $query2)
$ typeset -p queries
declare -a queries=([0]="SELECT" [1]="COUNT(id)" [2]="FROM" [3]="nodes" [4]="WHERE" [5]="label='KeywordList';" [6]="SELECT" [7]="COUNT(id)" [8]="FROM" [9]="nodes" [10]="WHERE" [11]="label='AuthorList';")
```

Notice the queries have been broken into separate tokens and stored as separate array entries.

As with your `psql` example that works, you need to quote the query variables when referencing them ... to include when populating the array, eg:

```
$ queries=("$query1" "$query2")
$ typeset -p queries
declare -a queries=([0]="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='KeywordList';" [1]="SELECT COUNT(id) FROM nodes WHERE label='AuthorList';")
```

Comment: glad I could help; `typeset -p <variable>` is a **BIG** help when trying to figure out what exactly is stored in a variable (especially arrays).